# Converting the file encoding with php

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with converting a csv file encoding from `ANSI` to `UTF-8`.

I wrote my self this function:

```
function prepareFileEncoding( $file, $encoding = "UTF-8" ){

    $file_content = file_get_contents( $file );

    if( !mb_check_encoding(  $file_content, $encoding ) ){
        file_put_contents( $file, mb_convert_encoding(  $file_content, $encoding ) );
    }
}
```

I have a File saved in `ANSI` and the same File saved in `UTF-8`.

```
file_ansi.csv
file_utf8.csv
```

So I actually have a script that imports data into a Database.

When I import the file that's encoded `utf8` everyting works as expacted. Since im from Germany I have some german letters like:

```
ä, ö, ü and ß
```

These are stored like this in DB.

When I run the `file_ansi.csv` than all words get cut from the special chars.

So if the word would be `Mütze` (hat in german) than it only stores `M` the rest gets cut of. So I thought, good... lets simply convert the encoding of the file.

When I build in my function than it converts the file into a `UTF-8 w/o BOM` and this causes the specialchars to turn into `?`.

**What can I do to solve this issu?**

**Is it possible to say that the convert function creats `UTF-8` and not `UTF-8 w/o BOM`?**

Comment: 3rd parameter to `mb_convert_encoding()` is missing, so internal encoding is used. The file is certainly not in `ANSI` as it's missing some german characters.

Comment: I added the optional 3rd parameter. I set it to `'ASCII'` and then it came up with some undecoded utf8. This actually helps me to solve this :)

Comment: What is this "ANSI format" that you talk about? In case you mean ASCII (a standard issued by ANSI) then there's nothing to do, as all ASCII files are valid UTF-8 files. However, you can't have e.g. umlauts in ASCII, so you probably have one of the codepages like ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1) or ISO-8859-15 (Latin 15). Also, "These are stored like this in DB." isn't helpful, as that may indicate UTF-8, HTML-escaped or one of the codepages. Lastly, for transcoding, use `iconv`, which was made for this task!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Ansi is what my notepad++ says so I sayed that. Also it doesnt matters how the data is stored in the DB, only that the data come correctly to the DB and the issue appears before writing to DB. And ANSI is almost same like ASCII, ANSI is 8bit and ASCII 7 bit. Anyways... Marek got me and it solved it :)